# SharePoint Framework Workbench Error - the requested operation is part of an experimental feature that is not supported in the current environment

Tags: web-part, client-side-rendering, spfx, spfx-tooling

I've just followed the instructions for the hello world sample for the SharePoint Framework Preview and I'm getting the error in the title when attempting to run the workbench on my sharepoint dev site.

I get a page that says "Sorry, something went wrong" and then `"The requested operation is part of an experimental feature that is not supported in the current environment."`

I've followed the instructions here to set the environment up:

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki/Setup-SharePoint-Tenant

It's step 6 in these instructions that I'm having trouble with:
https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki/HelloWorld-WebPart

Any thoughts greatly received.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As Wictor mentions, you need a developer tenant.  It sounds like there are some issues people are facing though.  While we are sorting out the issue, does the following tenant sign up work?  https://portal.microsoftonline.com/Signup/MainSignUp.aspx?OfferId=6881A1CB-F4EB-4db3-9F18-388898DAF510&DL=DEVELOPERPACK

That should give you a 30 day trial developer tenant.

Answer (score 3):

You *MUST* have an Office 365 Developer tenant at the moment to be able to use the Workbench. You get the O365 Developer tenants from your MSDN subscription, go to http://dev.office.com and follow instructions.

Comment: I've followed the instructions against my tenant for creating a developer site though as per the instructions?

Comment: A Developer site doesn't work - you need a Developer **tenant**

Comment: OK.  How would I tell if it's a developer tenant?  I think I've just signed up for one, but it looks the same as my other two tenants to me...  Thanks for the responses...

Comment: I actually don't know, for some reason I cannot create a new developer tenant - once you tried and failed via the MSDN subscription page - you're hosed...

Comment: E-mail accounts are easy to obtain. Just sayin' ;-)

Comment: If you go to your Office 365 Admin portal and check subscription details if your tenant, it should say Office 365 developer subscription.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to set up a developer tenant as I had previously had one set up (about two years ago) and they only last a year.  The message you get sugegsts this is one possibility along with proxy issues and other red herrings.

On Dana's advice (she is with Microsoft support) I used a personal email address I had to set up a new developer tenancy and this worked.

In a year's time I guess I'll be setting up another email address (or using a new business email address as I'm a contractor and change clients a couple of times a year each of which give me a new address) when this one runs out.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, setting up a new tenant with another personal email did the trick.  It's quite annoying since I now have three O365 tenants.  That's not good for anyone.. Ho hum!

Answer (score 0):

Rather annoyingly, I was required to set up yet another tenant (YAT?) for development.  I used the new sign up link with a personal email address.  It seems there is no real way to tell if it will work or not until you try it...